# How to close channel after fix amount of time with netty?

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I want connection to be closed after certain amount of time

Say, connection established at 8:00
netty client writing messages

```
channel.writeAndFlush(message).sync()
```

After 10 mins, at 8:10, connection should be closed if there is no writing process is being going on.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [WriteTimeoutHandler](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/WriteTimeoutHandler.html)? It sounds like it would do exactly what you want by triggering an exception if you start writing and the write ends up taking too long.